# sentiment analysis , feature selection

Tags: analysis, svm, sentiment-analysis, feature-selection

I want to know what are the appropriate tools for each step to analyse sentiment :
removing stopwords, 
stemming, 
Vector Representation of Text,
feature selection, 
classification,
how to pass from Vector Representation of Text to feature selection , is there any step to follow and an examlpe which describe those steps

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at Bing Liu's tutorial on sentiment analysis [here](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/Sentiment-Analysis-tutorial-AAAI-2011.pdf), and Pang & Lee's survey [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/llee/opinion-mining-sentiment-analysis-survey.html). They cover the different aspects of sentiment analysis and common approaches.